# Arrays `lineControl.every()` function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, return, undefined

```
const GAME_STATE = {
    'board': [
        [1, 1, 1],
        [null, null, null],
        [null, null, null]
    ],
    'overControl': false
}

...

function lineControl() {
    const { board } = GAME_STATE;
    board[0].every(e => e === 1);
}
```

I'm trying to make a Tic-Tac-Toe but my lineControl() funxtion returns `null`

Comment: returns undefined*

Comment: If you have changes to your Question, please edit it using the "edit" option on your post.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `lineControl` function like this

```
function lineControl() {
    const { board } = GAME_STATE;
    return board[0].every(e => e === 1);
}
```